# How do I select few random values from a datatable column

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0, random

I have a DataTable with a column `studentid`. It has 1000 records. I need to select some 30 random ids and insert them into a database table. Then, I need to exclude these 30 ids, select another 30 random ids, and... so on until 1000 records.

And, in every iteration, I will have a given number of ids, so only that many ids should be selected (the 300 is not constant, it may be 30, 25, 23, 24...).

Comment: Do you mean a DataTable from C#?

Comment: Anon-Yes It is in C#..

Comment: Why the sql-server tag?

Answer (score 2):

This may get you started:

```
--Create a temporary table
CREATE TABLE #temp (id INTEGER)
go

--Insert 30 randow ids into the #temp table, excluding any ids that were previously picked.    
-- run this line as many times as needed.
INSERT INTO #temp select top 30 id from [student] where [id] not in (select [id] from #temp) order by newid()
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an array with the 1,000 student ids and [shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) the array. Then just start at the beginning of the array and go forward.

If you have to be persistent, you can write the contents of the array to a temporary table and step through it sequentially.

Or, you could do:

```
SELECT id FROM table
ORDER BY RAND()
```

and write it to a temp table. I don't remember the SQL syntax. `SELECT INTO`? That'll put all of the id's into a table in random order and then you can pick them out 30 at a time, starting at the beginning.

Comment: @user3116746: Why would that matter? You're selecting just the IDs into a temporary table. Then you pull 30 IDs from the temporary table and select the records with those IDs from the original table.

Answer (score 0):

The use of some dynamic SQL may be tolerable here.

```
IF ( OBJECT_ID( 'tempdb.dbo.#t_Student' ) IS NULL )
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #t_Student
    (
        StudentID           INTEGER
    );

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @i  INTEGER;
        SET @i = 0;
    WHILE ( @i < 1000 )
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #t_Student ( StudentID )
        VALUES ( @i );
        SET @i = @i + 1;
    END;

    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
END;

IF ( OBJECT_ID( 'tempdb.dbo.#t_Processed' ) IS NOT NULL )
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #t_Processed;
END;

DECLARE @Random         INTEGER,
        @LowerBound     INTEGER,
        @UpperBound     INTEGER,
        @SQL            NVARCHAR( MAX );
    SET @LowerBound = 1;
    SET @UpperBound = 30;

CREATE TABLE #t_Processed
(
    StudentID           INTEGER
);

WHILE ( (   SELECT  COUNT( 1 )
            FROM    dbo.#t_Processed ) <
        (   SELECT  COUNT( 1 )
            FROM    dbo.#t_Student ) )
BEGIN
    SET @Random = ROUND( ( ( @UpperBound - @LowerBound ) * RAND() + @LowerBound ), 0 );

    SET @SQL = '
        SELECT  TOP ' + LEFT( @Random, 10 ) + ' StudentID
        FROM    #t_Student
        WHERE   StudentID NOT IN (  SELECT  StudentID
                                    FROM    #t_Processed )                          
        ORDER BY NEWID();';
    INSERT INTO #t_Processed ( StudentID )
    EXECUTE dbo.sp_executesql @statement = @SQL;
END;
GO
```